SLURM: Controller memory is not enabled. What to do?
When I do systemctl status slurmd I have:
systemd[1]: Started slurmd.service - Slurm node daemon.
slurmd[2145]: slurmd: error: Controller memory is not enabled!
slurmd[2145]: slurmd: slurmd version 22.05.8 started
slurmd[2145]: slurmd: CPUs=4 Boards=1 Sockets=1 Cores=4 Threads=1 Memory=1846 TmpDisk=59376 Uptime=478 CPUSpecList=(null) FeaturesAvail=(null) FeaturesActive=(null)

In slurm.conf I do not consider cgroup at all, so I have no idea how to fix this?
funny enough above it says Memory=1846 however in slurm.conf I set RealMemory=1646. So it is actually not reading my slurm.conf
the service is active, except for that error.
If I dig further, with slurmd -D -s I have:
slurmd: error: Controller cpuset is not enabled!
slurmd: error: Controller memory is not enabled!
slurmd: error: Controller memory is not enabled!
slurmd: error: Controller memory is not enabled!
slurmd: slurmd version 22.05.8 started
slurmd: killing old slurmd[2145]

and with systemctl status slurmd I also have
Main PID: 2145 (slurmd)
      Tasks: 1
        CPU: 81ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/slurmd.service
             └─2145 /usr/sbin/slurmd -D -s

so this CGroup somehow is there, but I never put it in slurm.conf so I wonder if I must put it
